# How can I load a .class file from a running jar into a Java Object in order to read the annotations inside the class file?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, testng

I have packaged a maven project using the maven assembly plugin in order to get a single jar file.

I packaged the following java classes from the folder `src/test/java` (TestNG tests) into a jar file.

The following classes are in the following path inside the jar:

```
    target/test-classes/com/example/tests/ByCitiesTest.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/tests/FullCycle3HoursTest.class
```

I can read the location of these classes running the jar but I want to load these classes in order to read the TestNG annotations (e.g: @Test, @DataProvider,...) and run them using a custom TestRunner I have developed.

I used the following code to read inside the jar and trying to load the .class file:

```
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
    CodeSource src = TestRunner.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    URL jar = src.getLocation();
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar.getPath());
    Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();
    if (src != null) {
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String entryName = ze.getName();
            if (entryName.contains("target") && entryName.contains(".class") && entryName.contains("test")) {
                System.out.println(entryName);
            }
        }

    }


    URL[] urls = {new URL("jar:file:" + jar.getPath() + "!/")};
    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
    InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream("target/test-classes/com/example/tests/ByCitiesTest.class");
    byte[] array = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(array.length);
    int length = in.read(array);
    while (length > 0) {
        out.write(array, 0, length);
        length = in.read(array);
    }
    Class testclass = classHandler.defineCustomClass("ByCitiesTest", out);
    XmlClass singleClass = new XmlClass(testclass.getName());
    classes.add(singleClass);
```

And the function `defineCustomClass`

```
public Class defineCustomClass(String name, ByteArrayOutputStream out) {
    return defineClass(name, out.toByteArray(), 0, out.size());
}
```

This function uses `defineClass` from the Java `ClassLoader` class.

And the error I get on execution is as follows:

```
    Current relative path is: /Users/root/path/of/the/project-webdriver
    target/test-classes/com/example/BaseByHoursTest.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/CardInformationPage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/ConfirmationPage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/ContactPage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/ExtrasPage.class        
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/HomePage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/HotelPage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/pages/ResultsPage.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/tests/ByCitiesTest.class
    target/test-classes/com/example/tests/FullCycle3HoursTest.class
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ByCitiesTest (wrong name: com/example/tests/ByCitiesTest)
```

I don't know which is the name of the class and how I can know that name. I tried to load the file into an `InputStream` and then try it to load it using a ClassLoader.

How can I load the file .class into java Class object? 
How can I read the annotations from these classes which are inside a jar file?

Comment: Do you know about junit @RunWith annotation.

Comment: It is not a problem of annotations, it is a problem of class objects.

Comment: What you want to do is easily solved by junit. However, why wouldnt Class.forName work for you when it is already in the classpath?

Comment: Do you have an example where I can see how the code is done?